# Unable to install the iOS build from the third party link and showing white icon only

Tags: iphone, build, udid, diawi

I am trying to install App from Diawi link on iPhone-7 but every-time its showing plane white iCon as attached below screen.

[image]

I have tried the following scenario and all are working fine:

- Tested App on other devices.
- Twice check device UDID (already added with provisioning profile)
- On simulator iCon showing properly for both iPhone7 and 7 Plus.
- Tested with same iOS version on iPhone 6s.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: In my case UDID was incorrect. Client provided me device UDID from third party tools and due to this got incorrect UDID.

- Make sure UDID which you are going to use in your App has been fetched from iTunes not from any third party tools.